# How to receive the message from stomp websocket with spring boot on android?

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, android-studio

I've got the simple WebSocket example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

```java
package com.example.chatservice.message;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class ChatController {
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        return new Greeting("Hello from chat!");
    }
}
```

and I'd like to receive the `Greeting` message from the spring server to an android app. I use https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid as a stomp client

```java
package com.example.chatapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;

import ua.naiksoftware.stomp.Stomp;
import ua.naiksoftware.stomp.client.StompClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private StompClient mStompClient;
    public static  final String TAG="StompClient";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_message);
        view.setOnClickListener(e->  new StompTask().execute(""));
    }

    private static class StompTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private StompClient mStompClient;
        String TAG="LongOperation";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            mStompClient = Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "http://10.0.2.2:8080/gs-guide-websocket/websocket");
            mStompClient.connect();

            mStompClient.topic("/topic/greetings").subscribe(topicMessage -> {
                Log.d(TAG, topicMessage.getPayload());
            });

            mStompClient.lifecycle().subscribe(lifecycleEvent -> {
                switch (lifecycleEvent.getType()) {

                    case OPENED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection opened");
                        break;

                    case ERROR:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error", lifecycleEvent.getException());
                        break;

                    case CLOSED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection closed");
                        break;
                }
            });

            return "Executed";
        }
    }
}
```

and the connection to the

`http://10.0.2.2:8080/gs-guide-websocket/websocket`

works, because the log shows it's connected

`2022-01-18 14:04:56.486 23717-23752/com.example.chatapp D/LongOperation: Stomp connection opened`

but it does not subscribe to the topic:

```java
mStompClient.topic("/topic/greetings").subscribe(topicMessage -> {
    Log.d(TAG, topicMessage.getPayload());
});
```

because when I set the breakpoint it doesn't ever hit it.

how can I receive this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everything looks awesome except `"http://10.0.2.2:8080/gs-guide-websocket/websocket"` should probably be `"ws://10.0.2.2:8080/gs-guide-websocket/websocket"` for the websocket.

The author of the librabry put this in their [example code](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid/blob/master/example-client/src/main/java/ua/naiksoftware/stompclientexample/MainActivity.java):

```
`mStompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP, "ws://" + ANDROID_EMULATOR_LOCALHOST + ":" + RestClient.SERVER_PORT + "/example-endpoint/websocket");`
```

Comment: I've also tried this. The same result :(. It connects to the websocket but does not subscribe to the topic

Comment: Another thing the author is doing is `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` which  is something you are not specifying, although that's probably not the issue. Have you tried logging the individual steps and seeing how far the logger goes? Does the backend give any meaningful feedback by any chance? This is an interesting problem :D

Comment: By any chance are you following [this spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)? If you are, have you tried going to `ws://10.0.2.2:8080/gs-guide-websocket` instead, or even from your PC?

Comment: I tried `ws://10.0.2.2:8080/gs-guide-websocket` it gives `Stomp connection closed` on the android. And I tried both `http://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket` and `http://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket/websocket` from my PC. the first one returns `Welcome to SockJS!` and the second one `Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".`

Comment: on my pc `ws://blabla` it says that this site cannot be reached

Comment: I've been dealing with this problem since yesterday morning and I tried every simple solution.

Comment: I had a look on reactivex docs and it says that `subscribeOn` [Asynchronously subscribes Subscribers to the current Flowable on the specified Scheduler.](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Flowable.html#subscribeOn-io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Scheduler-) I think the problem may be that we are doing the async stuff incorrectly. I'll give this a shot on my PC quickly

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with async, because on the main thread it also does not work. I tried to put a breakpoint in the `ChatController::greeting` and it's never hit.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I suppose you understand that if you don't send the proper message to the specified request topic, then you won't get anything here -

```
mStompClient.topic("/topic/greetings").subscribe(topicMessage -> {
    Log.d(TAG, topicMessage.getPayload());
});
```

Today I had the issue where when sending a message,

```
mStompClient.send(REQUEST_TOPIC, requestAsString)
```

I also did not receive anything in the subscription. The problem is that in addition to subscribing to the topic of receiving messages, you must subscribe to the topic of sending messages -

```
mStompClient.send(REQUEST_TOPIC, requestAsString)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(
                                {
                                //onComplete
                                }, { error ->
                                  error.safeLog()
                                })
```

Comment: The problem is already solved.