# StompClient does not receive data

Tags: java, android, spring-boot

I have the same issue as this [How to receive the message from stomp websocket with spring boot on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70756185/how-to-receive-the-message-from-stomp-websocket-with-spring-boot-on-android) but there is no answer to how to handle this problem for me. The logs show that the channel is open and data from the client comes to server-side

```java
 stompClient.topic("/topic/client-data")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(stompMessage -> {
            Log.d("AAAAAA", stompMessage.getPayload());
        });
```

I have this function, and the log shows completely nothing

Server:

```java
@RestController
@Controller
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("api/intent")
public class IntentController {

    @Autowired
    private IntentService service;

    @MessageMapping("/client-message")
    @SendTo("/topic/client-data")
    public IntentModel sendPostmanData(String message) throws Exception {
        if (message.equals("DATA")) {
            return service.sendPostmanBody();
        } else {
            return new IntentModel();
        }
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/inputData", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void getPostmanRequestBody(@RequestBody IntentModel request) {
        System.out.println(request);
        service.getPostmanBody(request);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/intent").withSockJS();;
    }
}
```

I haven't found out the solution for Android, please give any info if you had the same issue.